# SQL Server: Compare nullable column in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, nullable

I got a beginner's question about SQL server. I'm linking two tables with each other by setting a column of table A equal to a column in table B. Basically, my query looks like that:

```
SELECT A.nr, [...]
FROM A, B
WHERE A.id = B.id
AND [...]
```

My problem is now that the id column in the table B also has some null values. So, if B.id is null, the whole row won't be shown because the condition isn't met. But if B.id is null, I just want A.nr also to be null instead of the whole row just not showing up. How can I do that?

I thought about the following:

```
SELECT A.nr, [...]
FROM A, B
WHERE A.id = B.id OR B.id IS NULL
AND [...]
```

but then the column is just mixed with all the possible B.id rows, no?

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to write this logic is to use an explicit `JOIN`.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, standard `JOIN` syntax.

In SQL Server, you need to express this as:

```
SELECT A.nr, [...]
FROM A JOIN
     B
     ON (A.id = B.id OR (a.id IS NULL AND b.id IS NULL) )
WHERE . . .;
```

ANSI standard SQL has a comparison operator for this purpose, but SQL Server does not support it.  This is called a `NULL`-safe comparison:

```
SELECT A.nr, [...]
FROM A JOIN
     B
     ON A.id IS NOT DISTINCT FROM B.id 
WHERE . . .;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried it out, but now I still have the problem that the rows where A.nr is null are skipped. Do you know what I can do about it?

Comment: @user2497853 . . . That is not due to the `JOIN`.  It would be due to other conditions that you are applying.